STM32L432KC executes ISR from EXTI twice under certain conditions
The Problem
As part of my Computer Engineering class I've been working on a project for a stopwatch. It involves a button connected to a GPIO Port on the microcontroller which triggers an interrupt on a rising edge, i.e. when the button is pressed down. The interrupt handler then simply toggles the SysTick Timer on or off by toggling the enable bit in the SysTick Control Register.
The problem I'm having is that, on the surface, this interrupt does nothing. Upon closer inspection with GDB however, it seemed like the interrupt was being run twice. Thus, in the first handling of the interrupt, the SysTick Timer would be turned off, and on the next run it would be immediately turned on again. However, this only happens under (so far) two specific conditions, both of which have to be met:

The generated assembly code for the interrupt handler involves a bx LR to break out of the interrupt
The corresponding Interrupt Pending bit in the Pending Register is cleared immediately before exception return

I have asked two other classmates, and they were experiencing the same behaviour when they tried out my code. I have looked at it several times but see no issues with the software, besides point two above, but none of the resources I looked at described such behaviour.
Investigation
It is almost certainly not a bouncing issue, since interrupt resolves fine under different conditions, like pushing LR and then popping it into PC immediately after, and I have also put a capacitor in parallel with the push-button to debounce it, which has helped in all my other tests.
In trying to isolate the cause of the issue, I hooked up an LED to a different GPIO pin and toggling the corresponding Output Data Register bit the same way I did with the SysTick Enable bit, which caused the same issue, and there I could also see the doubled execution of the interrupt handler, since the LED would flash for a very brief amount of time.
One thing I haven't investigated yet is whether or not the Interrupt Pending Bit does indeed trigger the interrupt handler by itself. If that is the case, there may be some race condition with between the exception return sequence and the clear of the interrupt pending bit, causing the interrupt to be triggered twice in a row. I will try it out once I'm home, which will be in about 2-3 hours after posting. One clue that points to this being an issue with race conditions is that stepping through the handler with GDB "fixes" the issue, whereas continuing twice after setting a breakpoint on the function head does not.
Workaround
So far the best workaround seems to be to immediately clear the interrupt pending bit upon exception entry, or to force the push {LR} and pop {PC} instructions into the assembly code, however that second option seems a bit more volatile to me since the stack could end up with an extra LR value on it which will then likely mess up the restoration of the previous processor state.
In case anyone is willing to try and reproduce the issue, I have uploaded a stripped down version of the code on GitHub. It is made specifically for the STM32-L423KC, without using the HAL since that was part of the exercise.

It's because clearing the interrupt pending bit takes a bit of time, and if you return before it has cleared you'll get another interrupt. See proposed duplicate question (and the link its answer contains).
